# Android device keeps crashing on Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

When I run React Native on Expo, the IOS physical device is working at it should be but android physical device keeps crashing. Can someone please explain me why this keeps happening?[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYVoH.jpg)(I had to shrink down the image because the image took more than 2 mb)

Comment: Can you please add more detail like when it actually crashing, some initial code or etc ?

Comment: I added the error message that shows up on the top. It gives an error message saying that the expo keeps crashing.